# ie9 jquery div width calculation returning two different results

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have the following code which redistributes the rest width to all the divs:

```
var menuItems = $('.picNav .overlay .item, .picNav .overlay .home');

var parentWidth = 980;
var totalItemWidth = 0;
var restWidth;
var moduloWidth;
var resultWidth;

menuItems.css({ width: "" });

for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++)
{
    totalItemWidth += menuItems[i].offsetWidth;
}

restWidth = parentWidth - totalItemWidth;
moduloWidth = restWidth % menuItems.length;
restWidth -= moduloWidth;

resultWidth = restWidth / menuItems.length;

for (i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++)
{
    $(menuItems[i]).width($(menuItems[i]).width() + resultWidth);
}
$(menuItems[0]).width($(menuItems[0]).width() + moduloWidth);
```

this snippet works as expected in all current Browsers.
After some tests with IE9 though, i had the issue that sometimes the last element is being dropped to the next line.
When I debug the javascript it calculates the correct amount for totalItemWidth (in my case: 717px), if I don't debug (or skip the part where it calculates the totalItemWidth) it sometimes comes up with 658px.

I'm not sure if that's a loading issue, or if there's something else going on.

I would be happy if anybody could give me a little insight.

Cheers
Carlo

Comment: do you have images in the menuitems?

Comment: nope, it's a plain div with a jquery click

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a CSS property to `""` as you do in `.css({ width: "" });`. Use `width: "auto"` or a specific `%` or `px` instead.

Comment: hey mooseman, thanks for your reply. The line where i set the property to "" is just there for resetting the width, it doesn't change anything if i take it away.